# Unregistering e.preventDefault in reactJS method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I'm in situation where I need to fire a google analytic event onClicking a link. I wrote a handler for the purpose:

```
handleClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // --------------------------
   GA code ...
  // --------------------------
  // now how can I re-eanble the link
  // e.target.click() and similar methods are not working for me

}
```

But after GA event is fired, I couldn't find a way to unbind the preventDefault from the link (created with React's "link" component).

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by updating the state.
The below sample I have tried to  conditionally attach the event handler..
I have removed the handler attached to onClick event of the button after the first call.

I have also tried out conditionally executing **e.preventDefault** for the link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/MQnoVJKJR

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
    btnClicked: false,
    linkClicked: false,
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('button clicked');
    this.setState({
      btnClicked: true,
    });
  }
  handleLinkClick(e) {
    if (!this.state.linkClicked) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    this.setState({
      linkClicked: true,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={!this.state.btnClicked && this.handleClick.bind(this)}> // Binding onClick event to state change

            Click Me
          </button>
        </div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.co.in"
          target="_blank"
          onClick={this.handleLinkClick.bind(this)}
        >
          Go to Google.com
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks krishna, but it seems there is an issue. With is sample, when click the first time on the link, nothing will happen as the linkClicked is false.

Comment: Yes because I do not have any other code apart from updating the state. You would have GA code which willl get executed and on the next click you would be able to navigate to the link you clicked. You may modify according to your requirement.

Comment: Ok got it. But if we could have unbind the e.preventDefault - like some thing we did with jQuery - would be ideal for my case.

Comment: React does not have unbind() method as in jQuery but  here onClick event in bound to the state of react component `onClick={!this.state.btnClicked && this.handleClick}` so this would serve your purpose in React

Comment: Hi Krisna, can you please add some part of your code (significant) back to SO so that someone can use your answer in future? - Thanks